# Find files containing a particular Chinese text in Explorer in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

Can somebody help me find a reliable way to find all files in a directory that contain a particular Chinese string where I use Windows 8 and the search file type is mostly doc or docx?

In Windows XP my Explorer does this well, but in Windows 8 I did not have reliable results with the same files. Sometimes I got results, but not always and sometimes I did not get all the results that the search conditions specified.

Comment: did you select to search in "File contents"?

Comment: Use a decent file manager for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the Chinese language installed on your machine by going to Settings → Region And Language → Languages.

[image: Language settings on Windows 10]

Once you have installed the correct language, go to Control Panel → Indexing Options → Advanced → Rebuild to recreate the search index with the new language settings

[image: Rebuilding the index on Windows]

The rebuild will take some time, and you can track the progress on the indexing options page. Once it is done, you should be able to search for the Chinese words in the documents.

As a little background while you are waiting for the rebuild: For some languages if they aren't installed Windows search can still do an okay job, but Chinese and Japanese need to have the correct language pack installed. This is because they don't use spaces between words which makes it hard for the search to move through the text to find matches